Cycle in dependencies between targets 'React-jsi' and 'SDWebImageWebPCoder'; building could produce unreliable results in Xcode 16.1
Cycle in dependencies between targets 'React-jsi' and 'SDWebImageWebPCoder'; building could produce unreliable results.
While build app from xcode , I got this error
Prepare build
error: Cycle in dependencies between targets 'React-jsi' and 'SDWebImageWebPCoder'; building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle path: React-jsi → SDWebImageWebPCoder → React-jsi
Cycle details:
→ Target 'React-jsi': Libtool /Users/bhavinp/Workspace/ReactNativeWorkspace/RN_TextToSpeech/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-jsi/libReact-jsi.a normal
→ Target 'SDWebImageWebPCoder': Libtool /Users/bhavinp/Workspace/ReactNativeWorkspace/RN_TextToSpeech/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SDWebImageWebPCoder/libSDWebImageWebPCoder.a normal
System:
    OS: macOS 15.1
    CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
    Memory: 101.26 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 18.20.2 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 3.6.4 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 10.5.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2024.04.08.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.15.2 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 24.1, iOS 18.1, macOS 15.1, tvOS 18.1, visionOS 2.1, watchOS 11.1
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 23, 27, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35
      Build Tools: 29.0.2, 30.0.2, 30.0.3, 31.0.0, 33.0.0, 33.0.1, 34.0.0, 35.0.0
      System Images: android-26 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-34 | Google TV Intel x86 Atom, android-VanillaIceCream | Google Play Intel x86_64 Atom
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2024.1 AI-241.18034.62.2411.12169540
    Xcode: 16.1/16B40 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: javac 17 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0 
    react-native: 0.71.7 => 0.71.7 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found



Go to Project target
Select Pods
Select SDWebImageWebPCoder
Go to Build Phase
Put Headers above the Link Binary With Libraries
Clean Build Folder
Run app


